# Probability of choosing a colour pen on the second time, without replacement

Tags: probability

**The Question**

> Consider a drawer with $6$ pens: $2$ blue, $2$ red, $1$ yellow and $1$ green.
>   We choose two pens without replacement. What is the probability of extracting
>   one blue pen second?

**Answer given:** $21/50$

[image]

I've tried many different methods, including finding the probability of picking a blue pen then a blue pen and then multiplying it by the probability of picking a blue pen first. Then adding that to the probability of picking a non-blue pen then a blue pen, then multiplying it by the probability of picking up a non-blue pen first. That method gives me $1/3$, and all other methods give me answers don't get close to the answer given.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what "one blue pen second" means.  If all it means is that the second draw is blue, then the answer is $\frac 26$.  If it means that the second is blue AND the first is not-blue, then the answer is $\frac 46\times \frac 25$.  I have no idea where the given answer comes from.

Comment: @lulu I've added a picture of the solution the lecturer gave us but I'm still unable to understand it, especially where the 1/30 came from.

Comment: That's because it is nonsense.  The probability that the first draw is blue is $\frac 13$, obviously.  The probability that the second draw is then also blue is $\frac 15$.  Hence the probability $P(B_1\cap B_2)=\frac 1{15}$.  What text is this?

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the clarification! The lecturer must be wrong. It's just weekly questions he sets

Comment: Just to stress:  the probability that any given draw is blue is $\frac 26$.  There is nothing special about being the first, second, or sixth draw.  It's fine if the author wants to carefully go through the law of total probability to confirm this...that's a good exercise.  Just do it carefully.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Anybody can make a mistake at the board.

Comment: As an alternate way of computing $P(B_1\cap B_2)$:  suppose the pens are numbered $b_1,b_2,r_1,r_2,y,g$.  Then there are $6!$ equally probable ways of ordering them.  There are $2\times 4!$ ways of ordering them assuming the two blues come first (in some order).  Thus the answer is $\frac {2\times 4!}{6!}=\frac 2{6\times 5}=\frac 1{15}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your  law of total probability is wrong. The right formula is

$$\boxed{P(B_2)=P(B_2|B_1)\cdot P(B_1)+P(B_2|B_1^C)\cdot P(B_1^C)}$$

That´s a big mistake from your lecturer.

$=\frac15\cdot \frac{2}6+\frac{2}{5}\cdot \frac46=\frac2{30}+\frac8{30}=\frac{10}{30}=\frac13$

Interpretation of $P(B_2|B_1)$:

One blue pen is drawn first.  $5$ pens are remaining. One of them is blue. Thus the probability that the second drawn pen is blue is $\frac15$, given that the first drawn pen was blue.